# How does one find the maximum of a two variable function, bounded in a square?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

So suppose I have some function$$A= \frac{1}{16}\left(2a^2+2b^2-2b(a+1)+1\right)$$
with $0\leq a \leq b \leq 1$, of which I know that it has a minimum at $(\frac13, \frac23)$.
I also know the hessian to be a constant $H=\frac34$ and the gradient to be given by $$\nabla A = \frac{1}{16}\left(4a-2b,\;4b-2a-2\right).$$

This is an ever increasing function, but we wish to know the maximum in the region where $0\leq a\leq b \leq 1$. How do you do this? I suspect the corners to be equally valid maxima, but I wouldn't know how to prove it. (i.e. $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$).

**Edit:** My solution based on lord shark's comment:

> Suppose we set $b=0$, then $A = 1$, since $a\leq b$.
>
> Suppose we set $a=0$, then $A = \frac{1}{16}(2b^2-2b+1)$, which is symmetric about $\frac12$.
>
> Suppose we set $a=1$, then $A = 1$, since $a\leq b$.
>
> suppose we set $b=1$, then $A = \frac{1}{16}(2a^2-2a-1)$, which is symmetric about $\frac12$.
>
> Then from here we can see that $\max A = 1$.

Note that I've already proven the existence of only one critical point, so I don't have to consider local maxima.

Comment: Find the values at the corners, look for local maxima on the edges, look for local maxima in the interior. Find the biggest of these.

Comment: How could the hessian of a function in two variables be a scalar?

Comment: @user251257 The hessian is used interchangeably as meaning: 1) The hessian matrix. Or 2) The determinant of this matrix. In this context, we're talking about the second definition.

Comment: It’s convex, so for maxima, only corners need to be checked...

Comment: @MitchellFaas I don't get that determinant either. Though the correct one is also positive.

Comment: @user251257 Pairwise differentiating the determinant, we get: $$H = \frac1{16}
 \det\begin{bmatrix}
 4&-2\\-2&4
 \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{16}(16-4) =\frac{12}{16} =\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: @Macavity technically extreme points, not just corners, but they both agree here.

Comment: @MitchellFaas det isn't linear...

Comment: @user251257 Yeah, you're right. Only thing that changes is that it becomes $\frac{12}{16^2}$ though.